# CouchDB not working over https after certificate renewal

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, couchdb, lets-encrypt

After I renewed my certificate I cant’t access couchdb through https. Nothing changed in the configuration file. Only the renewal was done. It works over port 5984 without https but not on 6984 with https

My domain is: hotelbee.tk

I ran this command: sudo certbot --config-dir /opt/couchdb/letsencrypt renew

Runs on Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? What error do you see? What do your logs say?

Comment: No nothing. It just says This site can’t be reached The connection was reset.
When i `curl localhost:6984` (which is my https port for couchdb) I get `(56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer`

Answer (score 1):

I already found the solution. After I renew the certificate you had to give couchdb permission again to it.
This [article](https://www.joshmorony.com/creating-a-couchdb-database-on-an-ubuntu-server-digital-ocean/) helped. Set permission to the certificate files with `sudo chmod 600 path/to/cert.pem`
and at the end run `sudo chown -R couchdb /opt/couchdb/letsencrypt/` (path to your cert location)